# UIButton Label Showing 0 Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I've got a Custom Button class that I'm setting up the text for in my storyboard file. The text is a simple "Update Email Address" and does not change throughout the life of the app.

However, I have an image I want to add to the button, and when I do that, I set the image in the following way, in a method inside the common button class:

```
[self setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:iconName];
    CGFloat iconWidth = icon.size.width;
    [self setImage:icon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setWidth:self.width+iconWidth*2];
    [self setOriginX:self.x-iconWidth];
    [self setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -iconWidth*2, 0, 0)];

    CGFloat leftMargin = 10;
    CGFloat moveLeft = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width + self.titleLabel.x + leftMargin;
    [self setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, moveLeft , 0, 0)];
```

However, by setting it this way, it appears the titleLabel's width is 0 so the image isn't being set in the correct location on the button.

My thoughts on why this are happening are potentially because I never set the text programmatically, only in the storyboard, although that really doesn't make sense, it's all I got.

Does anyone see anything wrong here? If you need any other code let me know and I can post up the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

When do you do this? Maybe you are trying to do this after the resource was loaded but before the frames of all the elements are set.